# Translate SQL query to PySpark DataFrame query (a Percentile Ranking calculation)

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to translate this SQL query to PySpark DataFrame methods:

```
SELECT id_profile, indications, PERCENT_RANK()
OVER (PARTITION BY id_profile ORDER BY prediction DESC) AS rank FROM predictions
```

So `id_profile`, `indications` and `prediction` are columns from my `predictions` DataFrame.

I think I have to do this with `Window` methods, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("id_profile").orderBy(F.col("prediction").desc())

df.withColumn("rank", F.percent_rank().over(w))\
  .select("id_profile","indications","rank")
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! Do you know if these two different ways of doing this data processing should have the same performance (speed) ?

Comment: There shouldn’t b a difference in speed